# Quarter a given triangular meshregion

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

For a given , examplary simple, triangular meshregion

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, .2}, {.2, .2}, {.2, 1}, {0, 1}};
mreg = MeshRegion@ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> pts,"MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2,4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 6}}]}]
```

[image]

I would like to refine the mesh in such way, that every triangle, using the side midpoints, is splitted  into four new triangle elements.

Sounds simple, but I couldn't solve this   example for a "concave" region.

How to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: You can also make a second order mesh an then connect the second order element incidents to 4 first order Elements. Another alternative is to use the mesh refinement function.

Comment: @user21 Thanks, I tried `MeshRefinementFunction` but didn't succeed. My goal is to keep the original mesh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is probably a more efficient way. Just out for a Sunday drive:

```
mcoords = MeshCoordinates[mreg];
mdpts = MeshCells[mreg, 1] /. Line -> Line@*Sort;
mtri = MeshCells[mreg, 2];
newcoords = Block[{Line = Mean@mcoords[[#]] &}, mdpts];
mp2i = mdpts -> 
    Range[1 + Length@mcoords, Length@mcoords + Length@mdpts] // Thread;
newtri = 
  mtri /. 
     Polygon[pts_] :> 
      Append[
       Polygon[{#[[1]], Line@Sort@{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, 
           Line@Sort@{#[[3]], #[[1]]}}] & /@ 
        NestList[RotateLeft, pts, 2], 
       Polygon[Line@*Sort /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1]]] /. mp2i // 
   Flatten;
{mreg, MeshRegion[Join[mcoords, newcoords], newtri]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Probably I need some time to undestand your code. Hope I didn't disturb your sunday trip to much, have a nice day...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann :)  I symbolically represent the midpoint of each `Line` by the `Line` itself. (The `Line@*Sort` puts the points in a canonical order, so that `ReplaceAll` can be used later.)  The `Line` elements are then mapped to coordinates of the midpoints (`newcoords`) and the new indices of those coordinates (`md2i`). Then we construct the new triangles more or less by hand: Each vertex becomes a triangle with the adjacent midpoints, and the triangle of the midpoints is appended.

Comment: Very clever approach, have to elaborate... Thanks